# (No such file or directory) error when importing SQLite DB from external to internal storage on Android

Tags: android, mysql

I try to give my users the option of importing and exporting their databases.
Whenever I try importing a file, I get this error:

> E/tag: /storage_root/APPNAME/MYDB (No such file or directory)

The directory seems to be correct but somehow I can never open/copy the file. I tried many different options already.
All this code is inside of a Fragment.

Code:

```
 importSQL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_DB);
        }
    });
```

//

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("OnActivityResultImport", "Bitmap was selected " + requestCode + "   " + resultCode);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        switch (requestCode) {
            case GET_DB:
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                //Find DB to import

                String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();


                importDB(PathHolder);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

//

```
public void importDB(String path){

    if(isExternalStorageWritable()) {

        //check if it really is a valid SQL DB file
        if(isValidSQLite(path)) {

            String outputPath = exportSQL.getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().split("files")[0] + "databases/";
            Log.d("WritingDB", "storage is writeable\nReading DB from: " + path);

            String outputFile = "MYDB";
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {

                //create output directory if it doesn't exist
                File dir = new File(outputPath);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }


                in = new FileInputStream(path);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + outputFile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                in.close();
                in = null;

                // write the output file
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;


            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
                Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }


            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.exportSuccessMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thats not a valid DB!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

this error comes only when the path of DB directory is incorrect. try to put absolute path (all with static folder names) in code.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. This definitely helpy, but depending how the file was selected I get so many different paths, which are all not the absolute one.
like:

content://com.amaze.filemanager.FILE_PROVIDER/storage_root/DOWNLOADS

content://com.android.providers.downloads

content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DRzI4Dwk1Qa7...